# Word to refer to mountainous vs plain-dwelling populations?

Tags: synonyms

I will need to be writing on a subject of cultural differences between two populations/cultures in the context that one of them is located in the mountains and the other on a plateau/plain.

Is there a word I can use so that I don't repeat "people who live in the mountains" or "people who live on the plains"?

Thus say "The people who live in the mountains mainly work in harvesting wood and mining" becomes "X mainly work in harvesting wood and mining".

And "The people who live on the plains mainly raise cattle" becomes "Y mainly raise cattle".

Comment: **Plainsman** - someone who lives on the plains. [Reference](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/plainsman).

Comment: *highlander*, *lowlander*?

Comment: I agree with @Drew 's suggestion. Having used your own terms to define the two peoples referred to, you could use _higlander, lowlander_  thereafter and be confident of being understood.

Comment: @Drew I considered those terms but highlander tends to automatically make one think of Scots.

Answer (score 2):

- [mountain people](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/travel/capturing-appalachias-mountain-people-7194840/) or [mountain dwellers](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/mountain%20dweller)
- [plains dwellers](https://www.wordplays.com/crossword-solver/plains-dweller) or [plateau dwellers](https://books.google.com/books?id=iqjGZUxK5tkC&pg=PA132&lpg=PA132&dq=plateau%20dwellers&source=bl&ots=OCsa7IoxOI&sig=_sH3pxbCNcp8ggz_4mtyH37YzOo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigysnOltHZAhVJUK0KHQxQDVEQ6AEIUjAI#v=onepage&q=plateau%20dwellers&f=false) or [plains people](http://firstpeoplesofcanada.com/fp_groups/fp_plains1.html) or [plateau people](http://firstpeoplesofcanada.com/fp_groups/fp_plateau1.html)

You wouldn't capitalize them, unless you're talking about specific groups who have adopted the names.

Comment: +1. However I would also point out that these terms are not normally used for people living in urbane western society e.g the towns of Utah or Nevada or even in Alpine villages. They are normally only applied to rural communities in pre-industrial societies e.g in Africa.

Answer (score 0):

*[Savannah](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/savannah) dwellers* (or *people*), or *[Prairie](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prairie) dwellers* (or *people*) are fine for people on the plains, unless there might be some reason to use a generic *Plains dwellers* .
Savannahs and prairies are very suited to cattle raising. But savannah and  prairie have specific geographic locations in the minds of some.

I like *mountaineers* for those who lives in mountains. So does [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mountaineer). But some prefer to think of *mountainers* as mountain climbers.

If referring to high mountains, *[Alpine](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alpine) people* can work. *Mountain people* will also serve.
There are several options, depending on areas you are writting about, and your audience.

Most simply, you can use *Mountain people* and *Plains people*.

Comment: The savanna and the prairie are specific types of plains and not interchangeable with each other nor with other types of pains, such as steppes or more to the point the coastal plains where much of the world's population lives.

Comment: @choster certainly that is what is in many minds.  I articulated the caveat. The OP did not specify about what was being written. It is perfectly possible to write about "a prairie, or "savannah" without being specific as to where it might be. Or, for that matter, "a steppe". It would depend on the weather there. Coastal plains often have a lot of trees, and, unless deforested, areb't especial good for extensive cattle raising.

Comment: The point is that no educated person would call people in coastal Virginia "prairie" or "savanna" etc. dwellers to contrast with their Appalachian counterparts, likewise river Delta Vietnamese vs. montagnards, or lowland Scots vs. Highlanders. Demonstrate such usage in formal writing, please.

Comment: @choster...I take your point, however, I am not writing about diverse peoples, I was giving options with valid citations. Given that so far only the OP knows about what he is going to be writing, options seem reasonable to me. Should the OP weigh in on this, I will certainly provide such appropriate recommendations as I can.